# How to fix this error in contact form 7 in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have created a contact form using contact form 7 plugin in WordPress and uploaded onto server. When I am filling all the details and clicking the submit button, this error is showing :

> Failed to send your message. Please try later or contact the administrator by another method.

Can anyone tell why this error is showing ?

Comment: Turn on error reporting and/or look at the error log of your webserver.

Comment: See : http://contactform7.com/faq/after-submitting-the-form-i-get-an-error-message/

Comment: Please check mail tab of that form and add the from email id and other fields

Comment: All the info has been filled in the mail tab. Still it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

> disabled all plugins and After try to active contactform7 problems is
>   another plugin

Comment: Please reply with comments to the original question, no need to add new answer with single line.